# Exchange RestTemplate giving 400 Bad Request

Tags: resttemplate

I am using exchange for GET method in RestTemplate. But while passing the requestEntity in the exchange method i am getting 400-Bad Request.
Below is the code I am using.

Producing an URL:

```
@GetMapping("/getValues")
    public ResponseEntity<ValueResponse> getValueCall(@RequestBody AccountDTO accountDTO) {
        Map<Integer, ValueEntity> crmMap = new HashMap<Integer, ValueEntity>();
        int accountNumber = accountDTO.getAccountNumber();
        valueMap.put(1, new ValueEntity("A", "B", "Tier 1", "DU", "Indian"));
        valueMap.put(2, new CRMEntity("C", "D", "Tier 2", "DU", "American"));
        valueMap.put(3, new CRMEntity("E", "F", "Tier 3", "DU", "English"));
        valueMap.put(4, new CRMEntity("G", "H", "Tier 1", "DU", "Australian"));
        ValueResponse valueResponse = new ValueResponse();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, ValueEntity> entry : valueMap.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals(accountNumber)) {
                valueResponse.setAccountNumber(entry.getKey());
                valueResponse.setFirstName(entry.getValue().getFirstName());
                valueResponse.setLastName(entry.getValue().getLastName());
                valueResponse.setCustomerTier(entry.getValue().getCustomerTier());
                valueResponse.setCustomerType(entry.getValue().getCustomerType());
                valueResponse.setNationality(entry.getValue().getNationality());
                return new ResponseEntity<ValueResponse>(valueResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Consuming the URL:

```
public EnrollResponse enrollingUser(ValueDTO valueDTO) {
   MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, 
  String>();
  headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
  HttpEntity<ValueDTO> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<ValueDTO>(valueDTO, 
  headers);
  ResponseEntity<ValueResponse> enrollResponseEntity = 
  restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/getValues",
                HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,  ValueResponse.class);
  return enrollResponseEntity.getBody();
}
```

Entity and DTO:

```
public class ValueDTO { 
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private String gender;
    private String nationality;
    private String email;
    private String channelId;
    private int accountNumber;
    private String languageKnown;
//constructor
//getters and setters
}

public class ValueResponse {    
    private long accountNumber; 
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String customerTier;
    private String customerType;
    private String nationality;
//constructor
//getters and setters
}

public class ValueEntity {  
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String customerTier;
    private String customerType;
    private String nationality;
//constructor
//getters and setters
}
```

I tried accessing the producer URL from postman with Header as Content-Type:application/json and Body:
{
    "firstName":"A",
    "lastName" : "B",
    "dateOfBirth" : "12/12/12",
    "gender" : "Female",
    "nationality" : "Indian",
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "channelId" :"Values App",
    "accountNumber" : 1,
    "languageKnown" : "English"
}
as the valueDto object.

Console:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
    at com.smilesmember.domain.AccountDomain.enrollingUser(AccountDomain.java:184)
    at com.smilesmember.controller.SmilesMemberController.enrollWS(SmilesMemberController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: HttpEntity<ValueDTO> requestEntity you are passing ValueDTO but the GET api accept AccountDTO. Please check

Comment: Thats a typo mistake. It accepts ValueDTO itself.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code if it accepts ValueDTO as you mentioned

```
ResponseEntity<ValueResponse> enrollResponseEntity = 
  restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/getValues",
                HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,  new ParameterizedTypeReference<ValueResponse>() {});
```

Comment: Still the same after adding:  ResponseEntity<List<ValueResponse>> enrollResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/getValues",
    HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ValueResponse>>() {
    });

Comment: why you need List<ValueResponse> your api is returning return new ResponseEntity<ValueResponse>(valueResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

Comment: If i am doing : ```ResponseEntity<ValueResponse> enrollResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("localhost:8080/getValues", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ValueResponse>>() { }); ```Then there is compilation error showing type mismatch : Cannot convert from ResponseEntity<List<ValueResponse>> to ResponseEntity<ValueResponse>

Comment: I have updated the answer. you need to send new ParameterizedTypeReference<ValueResponse>() {}

Comment: After updating to new ParameterizedTypeReference<ValueResponse>() {}. It still gives ```org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 null```

Comment: are you sure your /getValues api takes ValueDTO as Body. ?
public ResponseEntity<ValueResponse> getValueCall(@RequestBody AccountDTO accountDTO)